# General regex about english words, numbers, length and specific symbols

Tags: python, regex

I am working in an NLP task and I want to do a general cleaning for a specific purpose that doesn't matter to explain further.

I want a function that

1. Remove non English words
2. Remove words that are full in capital
3. Remove words that have '-' in the beginning or the end
4. Remove words that have length less than 2 characters
5. Remove words that have only numbers

For example if I have the following string

```
'George -wants to play 123_134 foot-ball in _123pantis FOOTBALL ελλαδα 123'
```

the output should be

```
'George play 123_134 _123pantis'
```

The function that I have created already is the following:

```
def clean(text):
    # remove words that aren't in english words (isn't working)
    #text = re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]+', '', text)
    
    # remove words that are in capital
    text = re.sub(r'(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)', '', text)
    
    # remove words that start or have - in the middle (isn't working)
    text = re.sub(r'(\s)-\w+', '', text)
    
    # remove words that have length less than 2 characters (is working)
    text = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,2}\b', '', text)
    
    # remove words with only numbers 
    text = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', text) (isn't working)
    return text
```

The output is

```
  -  play _ foot-ball _  _pantis   ελλαδα
```

which is not what I need. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: it will help if you add also the expected output.

Comment: What about any other special characters? Would you need to account for punctuation or is any part of the string space-delimited? What about words like `George's car`. Is `George's` considered a valid word? Furthermore, with "non English", do you mean any words containing letters outside the Latin alphabet?

Comment: Also, why is `foot-ball` not included in the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in single `re.sub` call.

Search using this regex:

```py
(?:\b(?:\w+(?=-)|\w{2}|\d+|[A-Z]+|\w*[^\x01-\x7F]\w*)\b|-\w+)\s*
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCrCjm/1)

**Code:**

```py
import re

s = 'George -wants to play 123_134 foot-ball in _123pantis FOOTBALL ελλαδα 123'

r = re.sub(r'(?:\b(?:\w+(?=-)|\w{2}|\d+|[A-Z]+|\w*[^\x01-\x7F]\w*)\b|-\w+)\s*', '', s)

print (r)
# George play 123_134 _123pantis
```

[**Online Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/OJI65V)